# Use a superscript prime symbol in Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, symbols

I have the following issue:
In my references, I often have a γ' symbol in the title, which stands for gamma prime, a strengthening component in high-temperature alloys.
Please note that many journals, especially in the past formatted this as an apostrophe and not as a prime symbol. I should also add that I normally use biber for bibliography, but for some journals I have to switch to bibtex.

An exemplary title is:
"Lattice misfits in four binary Ni-Base γ/γ' alloys at ambient and elevated temperatures"

When I export it to Bibtex using my Citavi literature software, I obtain:
"title = {{Lattice misfits in four binary Ni-Base \textgreek{g}/\textgreek{g}' alloys at ambient and elevated temperatures}}"

How can I replace this apostrophe with some sort of $^\prime$ expression, so that I get a proper superscript prime symbol in the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write mathematics as usual, but should enclose the result in `{...}` to prevent interference for the processing.

```
@Article{example,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Lattice misfits in four binary {N}i-{B}ase
              {$\gamma/\gamma'$} alloys at ambient and elevated
              temperatures},
  journal =  {J. Jour.},
  year =     2000,
  pages =    {1--20}
}
```

With `\bibliographystyle{plain}` this prints as

[image: Sample output]

Note that I have not included the whole title in extra brackets `{...}`, but just marked the elements that need protection (capital letters and mathematics).  This allows the bibtex style to do is job as intended.